# Keycloak Identity Provider with Remember me

Tags: keycloak

We have an application using keycloak for authentication. In this keycloak we have an Identity Provider configured.

Current behavior is strange, IDP authentication (via qrcode) is successfully performed and the session is generated. If you close the browser and re-enter the application with IDP, the qrcode is not requested, because the session is still active, but the timeout is updated for the second access.

Is it possible to keep the session expiration time from the first login? And not update session expiration on each access via IDP?